# PDF ZOOMING is fading the text

Tags: iphone, pdf

i successfully download the pdf file and it's working fine. But the problem is zooming . when i m zooming the clarity is not as clear as originally.
need help..

thanks in advance.

--- goeff.

Comment: How much zooming? Only Hollywood and the TV industry have solved the problem of almost infinite zooming without losing resolution ... that was a *joke*, son - Foghorn Leghorn, aka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you zoom it simply stretches the display. Fontsizes and media resolutions remain the same.

Comment: it will be easy for me if u tell me about that method for changing  font size and resolution .

Comment: There is no way to zoom without quality loss.

Comment: how to  change the fontsize and media resolution